# How add element to collection using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

In my Spring/Thymeleaf/Hibernate project  I need ability add element to field (wich is List<>) of my editing object. How I an make it, since embedded  are not allowed?
Something like that:

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {
    @Id
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private List<String> steps;
}
```

And my thymeleaf template:

```
<form th:action="@{|/save/${recipe.id}|}" method="post" th:object="${recipe}">

<input type="hidden" th:field="${recipe.id}" th:value="${recipe.id}"/>
<input type="text" th:field="${recipe.name}" th:value="${recipe.name}"/>
<input type="text" th:field="${recipe.description}" th:value="${recipe.description}"/>

<input th:each="step : ${recipe.steps}" type="text" th:field="${step}" th:value="${step}"/>

<!-- And here I want make ability add new step element to List<String> steps -->
```

How to make it, not losing already edited data of Recipe object?
Add using `<form>` and `<button type="submit">`?
Or just using `<a href>`? How dont lose entered data then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, found solution, sure not ideal, but it works.
Added field to my class (it will be flag, what we should do in endpoint of form-action-url: add step to List and redirect to edit again or just save. And form have 2 submit buttons:  and ,  changes flag field to "step" by JavaScrypt, so I will know I have add element to List and redirect back. 
JavaScrypt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleAddedStep()
    {
        document.getElementById("recipeAddedFlag").value = "step";
    }
    function toggleAddedNothing()
    {
        document.getElementById("recipeAddedFlag").value = "";
    }
</script>
```